# Server stuck on "Intel Reference Code Execution"

Tags: linux, hardware, supermicro

Setup - Supermicro X10DRU-i+ motherboard, 2x Intel e5-2630v4:

- server started rebooting at random times
- had memory modules reseated and replaced, reseated CPUs
- reset CMOS, updated BIOS
- changed motherboard (!).

As soon as we replaced motherboard it actully booted and it got to load our live environment - but at initialization state we got kernel panic with error "`Not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler`".

However, after couple of tries the server returned to its previous state - doesn't pass past "`PEI--Intel Intel Reference Code Execution.. D8`".

According to the following [Oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20881_01/html/E20885/gkzpz.html)
`0xD8` is DXE error code for "Invalid password". Though that doesn't say much - I couldn't find what kind of password is it and how is it relevant to (most probably) HW issue.

Can anyone help with this? The only thing that comes to mind is to replace one (or both) CPUs.

Comment: don't you have support for your material ? Since it's visibly HW issue, it can be preferable to contact your support team :/